# Erlang: advantages to separate relx.config?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I always had a `rebar.config` and a `relx.config`. However, I read this page by the author of Learn you some Erlang: http://howistart.org/posts/erlang/1/, and he has the `relx` section in his `rebar.config` and no `relx.config`. Is there a pro/con to this? Should I stick them all in one file? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: There's no need to have relx.config separately unless you're using relx directly (or with another build tool like erlang.mk). If you're using rebar3, relx is integrated.
http://www.rebar3.org/docs/from-rebar-2x-to-rebar3

Comment: @spawn_think thanks! If you put that as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Rebar3, relx is integrated [From Rebar 2.x to Rebar3](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/from-rebar-2x-to-rebar3). Hence, there's no need to have relx.config separately unless you're using relx directly (or with another build tool like erlang.mk).